# How to find 1st alphabet of a link

Tags: selenium, ide

My XPath is `<a href="/education/computer-science-and-creativity">Computer Science and Creativity</a>`. In Selenium IDE how can I locate the 1st alphabet in Computer? Thanks

Comment: <a href="/education/computer-science-and-creativity">Computer Science and Creativity</a>

Comment: which language is your test's are written?

Answer (score 0):

In selenium IDE you can use JavaScript to extract 1st alphabet in a link text. Here are the steps for this:

1. Store the entire link text using `storeText` command. For example, this question's  link text "How to find 1st alphabet of a link"

   `<tr>
       <td>storeText</td>
       <td>css=a.question-hyperlink</td>
       <td>ftext</td>
   </tr>`
2. Then use `storeEval` command and a JavaScript to extract 1st char of a link text - in this example, it will extract 1st char "H" and stores it in variable `firstAlpha`

`<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['ftext'].charAt(0)</td>
    <td>firstAlpha</td>
</tr>`

3. Now you can use this variable that containing 1st char of a link text in another step/command, here I am just printing in log.

`<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${firstAlpha}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>`